# Visual Studio cannot find system headers

Tags: visual-studio

When I try to compile, Visual Studio cannot find the system headers. There are dozens of error messages of the kind `cannot open xy.h`, "xy" being ctype, errno etc., which are surely part of the distribution.

[Here is an image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkb3C.png)

Additionally, a system library cannot be found:

```
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'kernel32.lib' Project1    K:\Program Files\Visual Studio\coduri\Project1\LINK 1
```

I don't have a lot of experience with VS. Probably something very fundamental went wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Whatever you did, the installation is screwed up. Simply uninstall and re-install, following whatever procedure you followed. (Or, maybe, as a first step, create a new solution and project from scratch in order to make sure you didn't inadvertently delete a project property/path or such.)

Comment: did that like 5 times. each time tried something different.